# Getting Error while unpublishing the Page in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, cme

When unpublish the Page getting the below error in Tridion 2011.

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

When checked in Registry eventlogs had the full permissions.

Kindly let know what cause this error and did any other place needs to check any other type permissions.

**Update and stack trace:**

Issue was inconsistant. Some times Page is unpublishing successfully. But for the same user getting the error.

Stack Trace:

```
The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
StackTrace Information Details:
at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)
at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate)
at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName)
at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type)   atTridion.Extensions.Events.Utility.TridionEventLogger.log(String prefix, String message, LogLevel level, LogIcon icon)
at Tridion.Extensions.Events.Utility.TridionEventLogger.log(String prefix, String message, LogLevel level)
at App_EventSystem.APPEventHandler.log(String message, LogLevel logLevel)
at App_EventSystem.APPEventHandler.OnPageUnPublishPost(Page Page, UnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
atTridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)
   atTridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
atTridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.InternalCreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.CreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.UnPublish(IEnumerable`1 items, UnPublishInstruction unPublishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targetTypes, PublishPriority priority)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.UnPublish(IEnumerable`1 ids, UnPublishInstructionData unPublishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, Nullable`1 priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
at SyncInvokeUnPublish(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Please include stack trace, which will help to identify the location of the issue and greatly improve ability to help. Also did this start happening suddenly, or on a newly installed system? One of the issue might be installer did not properly register the event sources, or an event handler is trying access registry.

Comment: @TridionDev please use the edit feature on your question to add additional information, and NOT place that information in an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in an extension `App_EventSystem.APPEventHandler.OnPageUnPublishPost` trying to log something in the event log using `Tridion.Extensions.Events.Utility.TridionEventLogger.log`. Please fix the event system by taking a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564420/the-source-was-not-found-but-some-or-all-event-logs-could-not-be-searched) or disable the event system from Tridion.ContentManager.config.